# Finding the general term of a suite of suites

Tags: calculus

I am searching the general term of a suite of suites.
The suite s is constructed like this:

$s(1)= (1,1,1,1,1,1,...)$

$s(i)$ has for $k$-th term the sum of the first $k$ terms of $s(i-1)$: $s(2) = (1,2,3,4,5,...)$ and $s(3) = (1,3,6,10,15,21)$ (triangulary numbers).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the diagonals of Pascal's triangle.  Let $s(i,k)$ be term $k$ of $s(i)$ for $k = 0$ to $\infty$.  Then $$
s(i,k) = \binom{i+k-1}{k} = \frac{(i+k-1)!}{(i-1)!k!}.
$$
The individual entries in Pascal's triangle are called binomial coefficients because the rows of Pascal's triangle are the coefficients in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$.
The diagonals have a similar interpretation:  $s(i,k)$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the power series expansion of $1/(1-x)^i$.